# Rails routing using custom attribute rather than table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Using Rails 4.2, I want to create a custom route using an `attr_accessor` rather than a table column, but I can't get the `resource_path` method to work.

I want custom route like this: `/foos/the-title-parameterized-1` (where "`1`" is the `id` of the object).

`Foo` model:

```
#...
attr_accessor :slug
#dynamically generate a slug:
def slug
  "#{self.title.parameterize[0..200]}-#{self.id}"
end
#...
```

`routes.rb`:

```
get 'foos/:slug' => 'foos#show', :as => 'foo'
```

`foos_controller.rb`:

```
def show
  @foo = Foo.find params[:slug].split("-").last.to_i
end
```

In my `show` view, when I use helper method `foo_path` it returns the route using the `id` of the object rather than the `slug` like this: `/foos/1`. Is it possible to get this helper method to use the accessor method? Am I off track with this approach?

I would prefer to use [Friendly Id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) but I dont believe its possible without creating a `slug` column in my model table. I dont want to create a column because there are millions of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to override the [`to_param` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Integration.html#method-i-to_param) in your model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def to_param
    slug
  end

  # or
  alias :to_param :slug
end
```

You may also want to use the [`:constraints` option](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) in your route so that only URLs that match e.g. `/-\d+\z/` are matched.

Keep in mind also that, using this method, the path `/foos/i-am-not-this-foos-slug-123` will lead to the same record as `/foos/i-am-this-foos-slug-123`.

Comment: Didn't know about the constraints option - useful stuff, thank you.