# Can I use Friendly Id on a Rails model without having to create a slug column on the model table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

On Rails 4.2, I would like to use [Friendly Id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) for routing to a specific model, but dont wan't to create a slug column on the model table. I would instead prefer to use an accessor method on the model and dynamically generate the slug. Is this possible? I couldn't find this in the [documentation](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/).

Comment: Not really - if you have to dynamically compute the "slug" in Ruby that means you cannot query for records based on the slug. You would have to pull everything out and sort through it in ruby. What you want is most likely a custom method to create the slug.

Comment: Thanks @max i suspected that, which is why I asked another question related to creating the custom method to create a slug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658221/rails-routing-using-custom-attribute-rather-than-table-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this directly using friendly id because of the way it uses the slug to query the database ([relevant source](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb#L57)).

However it is not difficult to accomplish what you want. What you will need are two methods:

1. `Model#slug` method which will give you slug for a specific model
2. `Model.find_by_slug` method which will generate the relevant query for a specific slug.

Now in your controllers you can use `Model.find_by_slug` to get the relevant model from the path params. However implementing this method might be tricky especially if your `Model#slug` uses a non-reversible slugging implementation like [Slugify](https://github.com/Slicertje/Slugify) because it simply get rids of unrecognized characters in text and normalizes multiple things to same character (eg. _ and - to -)

You can use `URI::Escape.encode` and `URI::Escape.decode` but you will end up with somewhat ugly slugs.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658221/rails-routing-using-custom-attribute-rather-than-table-column) I went with the following approach for custom routing based on dynamic slug.

I want custom route like this: `/foos/the-title-parameterized-1` (where "`1`" is the `id` of the `Foo` object).

`Foo` model:

```
#...
attr_accessor :slug
#dynamically generate a slug, the Rails `parameterize` 
#handles transforming of ugly url characters such as 
#unicode or spaces:
def slug
  "#{self.title.parameterize[0..200]}-#{self.id}"
end
def to_param
  slug
end 
#...
```

`routes.rb`:

```
get 'foos/:slug' => 'foos#show', :as => 'foo'
```

`foos_controller.rb`:

```
def show
  @foo = Foo.find params[:slug].split("-").last.to_i
end
```

In my `show` view, I am able to use the default url helper method `foo_path`.